# Алгоритм упрощения математического выражения с переменными

Tags: алгоритм, математика, дерево, интерпретатор

Здравствуйте! Задача - по возможности упростить математическое выражение. Упростить - значит привести к более короткому виду. Выражение хранится в обратной польской записи, или в виде дерева. Например, выражение `x*2-(x+x)` хранится в виде дерева -

```
     (-)
     / \
   (*)  (+)
  /  \  / \
(x) (2)(x)(x)
```

или в ОПЗ - `x2*xx+-`
Подскажите, какие есть для этого алгоритмы.

Answer (score 2):

Можно попробовать воспользоваться готовым решением [wolframalpha API](http://products.wolframalpha.com/api/), если это годится для вашей задачи.

Comment: Интересуют именно алгоритмы, так как интересно все сделать своими руками. Но посмотрю, спасибо.